# C# - Cannot Marshal IntPtr To String Correctly

Tags: c#, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit

This line of code has been baffling me!

```
string s = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)((Int32)Buffer + 
            Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Struct))));
```

Here is the rest of the function.

```
            Api.LvItem lvItem = new Api.LvItem();
            IntPtr lpLocalBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
            uint pid;
            uint thread = Api.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pid);
            IntPtr hProcess = Api.OpenProcess(0x001f0fff, false, (int)pid);
            IntPtr lpRemoteBuffer = Api.VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, IntPtr.Zero, 1024, 0x1000, 4);
            lvItem.mask = 1;
            lvItem.iItem = index;
            lvItem.iSubItem = subitem;
            lvItem.pszText = (IntPtr)((int)lpRemoteBuffer + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Api.LvItem)));
            lvItem.cchTextMax = 50;
            Api.WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpRemoteBuffer, ref lvItem, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Api.LvItem)), 0);
            Api.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x1005, IntPtr.Zero, lpRemoteBuffer);
            Api.ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpRemoteBuffer, lpLocalBuffer, 1024, 0);
            string ret = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)((int)lpLocalBuffer + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Api.LvItem))));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)lpLocalBuffer);
            Api.VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, lpRemoteBuffer, 0, 0x8000);
            Api.CloseHandle(hProcess);
            return ret;
```

This code is used to get the text of each of the items in a listview of another process. I followed code (semi) from here : http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2009/08/archive-hacking-my-way-across-process.html

I'm sorry about the use of 0x1005. That's the code for the `LV_GETITEM` message.

I've narrowed it down to being related to the platform. It works on x64 and AnyCPU, while it does not work on x86. how would I go about changing the size differences in memory allocation, etc

It returns the value correctly when used in a console application. But when I use this code (and the rest of it) in a .DLL which is invoked via reflection, the code returns a string which is not correct. It appears empty, but is not in fact null. Perhaps just white space...

Has anybody had a similar experience with this trouble marshaling? It's been puzzling me for a good three hours now...

ANY help or ANY ideas or ANYTHING is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could be a 64 bit pointer truncation but that would most likely lead to access violation. So probably the content beyond the end of the struct really is empty. Why don't you give us a complete program that illustrates the fault. Otherwise we have to guess. You've got a complete program. It's not fair that we don't

Comment: Hi David, I've narrowed it down to being related to the platform. It works on x64 and AnyCPU, while it does not work on x86. I think I can take it from here now, but any advice is helpful. I am running a x64 bit version of Windows.

Comment: Also, how would I go about changing the size differences in memory allocation, etc.

Comment: I've no idea. You didn't show enough code. If you insist on keeping it to yourself, I cannot help you.

Comment: Here is the function, was too long for a comment. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=793X6PS5

Comment: Add it to the question as an edit. Don't put the details in an off site link.

Comment: Er, you should have told us that you were reading the memory of another process. You are keeping far too may details from us. Please bare all and spill the beans. What are you doing? What applications's list view are you poking at? And why are you using those magic numbers? Now I have to go and look up `0x1005`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updates and further information. You've been very good. And I upvote for your efforts. Anyway, I've given you my answer now. If I were you I would give up on making this work from a 32 bit process and always make sure that your process matched the bitness of the target process.

Comment: The window message requires two buffers, one for the structure and another for the string.  The code uses a hack to use only one buffer, easier that way, putting the string buffer at the end of the struct.  But that doesn't work well since the structure has a different size on different versions of Windows.  Just arbitrarily add 42.  Only ever try to use this in a 32-bit program hacking another 32-bit process, mixing isn't going to work.

Comment: @Hans There's lots more wrong than the location if the string buffer. Even if the string buffer was separate then the code would fail.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to read the memory of another process. You are sending an `LV_GETITEM` message to a list view control. This requires you to allocate memory in the virtual address space of that other process. Which you did with the call to `VirtualAllocEx`.

So far so good, but here's the kicker. You need the struct that you allocate to be the right layout for the target process. Now, let's assume that the target process is a 64 bit process. In which case the struct contains 64 bit pointers. When your process is also 64 bit then the struct that you defined will have 64 bit pointers. But when your process is 32 bit, any pointers in the struct will be 32 bit.

So, now we have a situation where the struct in your process has a different layout from the struct in the target process. That mismatch is enough to make all of this effort fail. In order to have any chance of making this work, you would need to declare your struct so that its layout matched the 64 bit layout. Given that you are only accessing a handful of fields, it may just be simpler to allocate a block of memory the right size (perhaps a byte array) and read/write the fields manually. And avoid struct marshalling.

Even then I am doubtful that a 32 bit process is even able to poke at a 64 bit process that way. You can do it in the other direction, from a 64 bit process to a 32 bit process. But I have tried and never succeeded in the direction that you are attempting.

All the indications are that you should stick to a 64 bit processes for this task. Or alternatively find an officially supported way to do whatever it is you are doing. For example, if you just want to read the contents of an explorer view, there's a shell API for that.

---

As an aside, please stop using magic constants instead of message identifier names. Nobody likes to try and understand what `0x1005` means. Declare a constant named `LV_GETITEM`. You also appear to perform no error checking at all. That's also going to make life hard for you. If one of the API calls fails, how will you ever find out about that?

Comment: Is this helpful, or are you looking for more? Do you understand the point I am making?

Comment: Yeah I do get what you are saying, but I need the process to be 32 bit...no exception. So in my case you are saying that I need to find the size of the LVITEM struct in a 64 bit structure and allocate the memory manually through a byte[] of that size?

Comment: Yes, instead of using a struct and marshalling that, use a byte array. Or use a struct and replace the pointers with `long`, i.e. 64 bit integer. Anyway, even when you match everything up I'm still not convinced it's even possible from a 32 bit process. Are you looking for more help?